# Does Entity Translation hijack i18n's operations?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'd ideally like to use i18n to handle backend translation but use entity translation to maintain multiple language versions for each content node.

Does this require a lot of extra work or lead to caveats? I'm hoping they just handle different sides of the translation puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult or complicated, you just need to know what to do, where and using what. Have a look at [Drupal 7 Multilingual Sites](http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-multilingual-sites/book) book, it has pretty good explanation of the whole process. Essentially, yes, Entity Translation plus i18n modules would take care of most of the things for you.